# not able to fetch data from get request

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to fetch data from an api by subscribing it from a service. But it returns false.

> **service.ts**

```
fetch_userdata(){
var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + 
localStorage.getItem('user_token'));

var options =  {
  headers: headers
};
return this.httpClient.get('api/auth/fetch_users',options)
}
```

> **component.ts**

```
constructor(private Authentication:AuthService){}

getUsersFromServices():void{

this.Authentication.fetch_userdata().subscribe(
  (data) =>{      
    console.log(data);         
  },err =>{
    console.log('error occured');
  }
)
}
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNr37.png)

Comment: What does the network tab say for the request? (or the error)

Comment: log the error and take a look at it. `console.log(err)` then you should know whats going on, also edit your post and provide the error output pls if the output doesn't help you, then i can take look at.

Comment: It shows a 401 unauthorized error. But 401 usually comes up when we give invalid login credentials. But I'm able to login. After logging in I'm trying to fetch the data from the api. But I'm not able to.

Comment: Okay, so is the token added successfully in the request?

Comment: yes, it is added successfully

Comment: So have you checked the backend, is the token header supposed to look like that?

Comment: yes the token header is right

Comment: do you receive any message in the backend? something like "unauthorized"

Comment: I tested the api in postman and i'm able to see the data. There are no issues.